# msql php datetime query syntax

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, syntax

I am having a bit of trouble writing a mysqli query that queries between dates.

The column in my mysql database is a datetime column.

The query I have written in php looks like this

```
$sessions = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT s.idSession, s.idUser, 
    FROM rempad.Session AS s WHERE s.idUser = 12 AND s.start BETWEEN '2013-04-28' AND '2013-05-28'");
```

I have tried escaping the dates like \'2013-04-28\'

I have also tried casting as datetime like: DATETIME(s.start) BETWEEN DATETIME('2013-04-28') AND ...

But that doesn't work.

I have tested the SQL syntax in Mysql workbench so I know that the query returns values, but I can't seem to get it right in php.

Any ideas?  I can't find any examples online.

Thanks in advance
L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it and it worked as:

```
query($db,"SELECT s.idSession, s.idUser
    FROM rempad.Session s WHERE s.idUser = 12 AND s.start BETWEEN '2013-04-28' AND '2013-05-28'");
```

Removed a comma and 'as' after table name.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I was going blind looking at it.